# Interpreting F# garbage collection report

Tags: memory-management, f#, garbage-collection

I have a fairly complex F# application, and I use a F# script to check its performance using the `#time` directive. The idea is that I run the script after changes to the code to keep track of  performances and avoid introducing speed or memory problems.

The report I was getting was something like this:

```
Real: 00:00:02.908, CPU: 00:00:02.948, GC gen0: 237, gen1: 3, gen2: 1
```

but after the last change I get this:

```
Real: 00:00:03.058, CPU: 00:00:03.057, GC gen0: 262, gen1: 262, gen2: 0
```

and I have some trouble figuring out what's going on.

More generation 1 garbage collection means (?) that there are more long-lived object that survive garbage collection in generation 0 - but why the sudden jump from 3 to 262? And why the number of garbage collection on generation 0 and 1 are identical? If for some reason after the code changes there are more long-lived objects I would have expected something like:

```
Real: 00:00:02.908, CPU: 00:00:02.948, GC gen0: 212, gen1: 54, gen2: 1
```

i.e. the total number of garbage collected objects being similar but with more on generation 1.

Or am I totally misunderstanding those numbers (I could not find a description in the documentation)?

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments I totally misunderstood the numbers: they are the number of garbage collections executed for each generation, not the number of objects.

Having said that I am even more puzzled: it seems that my application put the memory in such a state that every generation-0 garbage collection triggers also a generation-1 one, and I cannot imagine what this state could be. I tried various test programs to replicate such behavior without luck.

I still have to try the profilers as suggested in the comments and pad's answer.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried the CLR profiler as suggested in the comments - to do it I converted my F# script into a program and run it from the profiler.

The report I get is completely different from the `#time` one - garbage collections:

- generation 0: 279
- generation 1: 5
- generation 2: 2.

Mistery - strage side-effect of using FSI.exe compared with a stand-alone program? Bug in `#time`?

Comment: The numbers are actually the number of collections at that generation - The printing function is at https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs - line 124.

Comment: Also, if you are really worried about memory usage the CLR profiler http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273 provides good information which is much more detailed than what you get from `#time`

Comment: I would say the difference in number of GC runs would be standalone vs interpreter - the GC count in FSI includes GC of things relating to compiling / optimizing your code which is not in a standalone version.  I would suggest that looking at GC counts is not a good performance metric - actual run time is far better.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: thanks. Probably you're right - I am giving up and sticking to the execution time as you suggest, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

.NET GC is a three-generation GC. As John Palmer pointed out, the last three numbers are [the number of collections run](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#L124) at these generations. Bigger numbers in `gen1` and `gen2` often indicate bad performance since GC has to mark those unused objects again and again in each garbage collection process. For more in depth introduction of .NET GC, take a look at [this nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/03/02/back-to-basics-generational-garbage-collection.aspx).

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Make sure to "Reset Sessions" between two measurements so that unused objects of the first session doesn't have an influence on the second one.
2. Find three bigger inputs to measure. Though execution times in these two reports are similar, I would expect the first approach to be more scalable. It's great if you have several input sizes to test scalability.
3. Measure a few times to record a pattern because you may just observe an *abnormal* session.
4. If in doubt, do a [full-range profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242740%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio. Their reports are much more comprehensive and reliable for performance prediction.

Comment: I believe it is the number of collections run - not the number of objects collected - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collectioncount.aspx